# iOS 7 Only App Crashes at Startup

Tags: ios, crash, ios7

I recently changed my xcode project to be iOS 7 only instead of supporting iOS 5.
After making this change as soon as the app starts I get this message in the console.

```
-[UICachedDeviceWhiteColor shadowColor]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x156f22f0
```

I'm not sure what is causing this. But using the debugger it seems like my app delegate is crashing at the first line of code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController; //this line is where it crashes

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the stack trace. What does the tab controller do when it loads it's view / NIB? What is in the default tab?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You probably did what I did, and overzealously cut and replaced the compiler warnings for UITextAttributeTextShadowColor and UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset. So you had code that looked like this:

```
NSDictionary *titleAttributes = @{UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                  UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor blackColor],
                                  UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(1, 0)],
                                  UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont titleBolder]};
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributes];
```

and replaced them both with NSShadowAttributeName, and ended up with some code like this:

```
NSDictionary *titleAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                  NSShadowAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor],
                                  NSShadowAttributeName: [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(1, 0)],
                                  NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont titleBolder]};
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributes];
```

What you need to do is have one attribute NSShadowAttributeName, and create an instance of NSShadow that contains the shadow color and shadow offset.

```
NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 0);
NSDictionary *titleAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                  NSShadowAttributeName: shadow,
                                  NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont titleBolder]};
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:titleAttributes];
```

Comment: Half an hour, is that all ? By the way [NSShadow.alloc init] was correct syntax regarding your edit.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises due to giving different NSAttributedString.key and value to attributed String.

***Error***:
let prefixAttribute = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 11.0),
            NSFontAttributeName:  UIColor.darkGray]

**Solved:**
let prefixAttribute = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 11.0),
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName:  UIColor.darkGray]

I have interchanged colorarrtibute with font and vice versa