# UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset is Deprecated

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I am trying to addapt my code to iOS 7.

```
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                            UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:214.0f/255.0f green:210.0f/255.0f blue:197.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f],
                      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.750f],
                     UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f)]
```

I am getting a few errors, `UITextAttributeColor is deprecated`, `UITextAttributeTextShadowColor is deprecated`, and `UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset is deprecated`.

Comment: Click here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968305/ios-7-only-app-crashes-at-startup

Answer (score 34):

```
NSShadow *shadow = [NSShadow new];
[shadow setShadowColor: [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.750f]];
[shadow setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:214.0f/255.0f green:210.0f/255.0f blue:197.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f],
  NSShadowAttributeName: shadow]
}];
```

Answer (score 6):

```c
NSShadow *shadow = [NSShadow new];
[shadow setShadowColor : [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.750f]];
[shadow setShadowOffset : CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f)];

[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
@{ 
    NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:10.0f],
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor grayColor],
    NSShadowAttributeName: shadow
}
forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
@{ 
    NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:10.0f],
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],
    NSShadowAttributeName : shadow
}
forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Comment: This answer is not very well structured and hard to understand. Could you explain a bit what the notation means? As it is it#s probably not very useful.

Comment: Actually it's a pretty good code sample, but agree it's missing explanations

Answer (score 2):

```
UIColor *blue = [UIColor colorWithRed:64.0/255.0
                                green:119.0/255.0
                                 blue:255.0/255.0
                                alpha:1.0];

NSShadow *shadow = [NSShadow.alloc init];
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];

NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                              NSForegroundColorAttributeName: blue,
                              NSShadowAttributeName: shadow
                              };

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```